# Use Amazon repo in Centos 7

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos7, nfs, amazon-efs

I set up a Centos 7 instance on EC2 and i need to mount a couple of EFS filesystems.

Because Centos 7 and Amazon Linux 2 are pretty similar, I am wondering if could be possible to add `Amazon Linux Extras` in order to use `amazon-efs-utils` to mount EFS file system.

I know that I can use traditional NFS configuration in `/etc/fstab`, but if I can find a solution with EFS utils I prefer

Someone here already tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Pretty similar"* in the regard that Amazon Linux 2 is based om RHEL/CentOS with the same package management system  with `rpm` and `yum` commands and the same default locations for configuration files and such.

But *as far as I know* there is no guaranteed or implied binary compatibility for packages between those two distributions and for many components Amazon Linux 2 has even decided to use different version of the upstream community project compared to what RHEL7 uses.

Therefore: **No** you can't use the Amazon Linux 2 repository for RHEL 7.

On what to do instead, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/using-amazon-efs-utils.html#installing-other-distro

> ## Installing the amazon-efs-utils Package on Other Linux Distributions
>
> If you don't want to get the amazon-efs-utils package from Amazon Linux or Amazon Linux 2 AMIs, the amazon-efs-utils package is also available on GitHub.

Comment: @hbrujin Thanks for your comment and for the link, you are right about "pretty similar". Besides binary compatibility, passing from Amazon Linux 2 to Centos, it lacks many features that I have in other instances (I don't want install odd repos from around the internet such as codeguru for http/2 and remi repo for PHP 7).
Luckily it is just a test for an application and is not a production environment set up.
Considering all elements including your comment, going in production with Centos 7 rather than Amazon Linux is not such good choice.
I will definitely roll back everything...

Comment: Amazon Linux was forked from CentOS 5 (!!!) and diverged so far from it that it hasn't been compatible for many years. Amazon Linux 2 was forked from CentOS 7, and has already diverged far enough that many packages are no longer compatible. Neither distro has any stability promises, which is usually what catches people out.